# Gson streaming api not reading the whole document

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a json which is invalid. But still I have to parse by parsing or whatsoever means.
Here is the json:

```
{"priceAgreementLineDetails":[{"catalogue":{"assetClassDetails":[{}],"assetClassRequired":null,"baseUnitofMeasure":"PMI","bomParent":"Yes","commodityCodeTaric":"84158200","enLanguageKey":"EN","enMaterialLongText":"Lenovo Privacy Filter for 14" Notebooks ( L, T and X1 Carbon)"","grossWeightInKg":null,"height":null,"heightLengthWidthUnit":null,"length":null,"manufacturerPartNumber":"","materialLongDescription":"Lenovo Privacy Filter for 14" Notebooks ( L, T and X1 Carbon)"","physicalCategory":"Physical","volume":null,"volumeUnit":null,"width":null,"xxLanguageKey":null,"xxMaterialLongText":null},"catalogueStatus":"ACTIVE","catalogueStatusTimestamp":"2021-05-11T04:34:52.097Z","comment":null,"commercial":{"appliedVoucher":null,"commitmentDateCategory":null,"discountDateCategory":"custom","manufacturer":"test123","materialDescription":"dsds","materialGroupL4":"K205 - ERP Software & Licenses","netPrice":"7000.00","plannedDeliveryTime":"3","priceAdjustments":null,"priceBookCurrency":"EUR","priceErosionDetails":[{"discount":"5.00","validFrom":"2017-06-01T12:00:00.000Z","validTo":"2022-06-01T12:00:00.000Z"}],"priceUnit":"1","sapContractLineId":"1","supplierPartNumber":"TESTING12321","validFromDate":"2017-06-01T12:00:00.000Z","validToDate":"2022-06-01T12:00:00.000Z","volumeCommitment":null,"volumeDiscounts":null,"volumeTierDiscounts":null},"customGroup":null,"index":null,"isDeleted":false,"isReviewed":true,"lastSaveBy":null,"lastSaveDateTime":null,"lineStatus":"COMPLETE","priceReference":"Purchase Order Date"},{"catalogue":{"assetClassDetails":[{}],"assetClassRequired":null,"baseUnitofMeasure":"PMI","bomParent":"Yes","commodityCodeTaric":"84158200","enLanguageKey":"EN","enMaterialLongText":"(ksjdiusd)","grossWeightInKg":null,"height":null,"heightLengthWidthUnit":null,"length":null,"manufacturerPartNumber":"","materialLongDescription":"(ksjdiusd)","physicalCategory":"Physical","volume":null,"volumeUnit":null,"width":null,"xxLanguageKey":null,"xxMaterialLongText":null},"catalogueStatus":"ACTIVE","catalogueStatusTimestamp":"2021-05-11T04:34:52.097Z","comment":null,"commercial":{"appliedVoucher":null,"commitmentDateCategory":null,"discountDateCategory":null,"manufacturer":"test123","materialDescription":"dsds1","materialGroupL4":"K103 - Customer Management (Billing & CRM) Software & Licenses etc.","netPrice":"5000.00","plannedDeliveryTime":"3","priceAdjustments":null,"priceBookCurrency":"EUR","priceErosionDetails":null,"priceUnit":"1","sapContractLineId":"2","supplierPartNumber":"TESTING123421","validFromDate":"2017-06-01T12:00:00.000Z","validToDate":"2022-06-01T12:00:00.000Z","volumeCommitment":null,"volumeDiscounts":null,"volumeTierDiscounts":null},"customGroup":null,"index":null,"isDeleted":false,"isReviewed":true,"lastSaveBy":null,"lastSaveDateTime":null,"lineStatus":"COMPLETE","priceReference":null},{"catalogue":{"assetClassDetails":[{}],"assetClassRequired":null,"baseUnitofMeasure":"PMI","bomParent":"Yes","commodityCodeTaric":"84158200","enLanguageKey":"EN","enMaterialLongText":"(ks) "di"","grossWeightInKg":null,"height":null,"heightLengthWidthUnit":null,"length":null,"manufacturerPartNumber":"","materialLongDescription":"(ks) "di"","physicalCategory":"Physical","volume":null,"volumeUnit":null,"width":null,"xxLanguageKey":null,"xxMaterialLongText":null},"catalogueStatus":"ACTIVE","catalogueStatusTimestamp":"2021-05-11T04:34:54.353Z","comment":null,"commercial":{"appliedVoucher":null,"commitmentDateCategory":null,"discountDateCategory":null,"manufacturer":"test123","materialDescription":"dsds2","materialGroupL4":"K103 - Customer Management (Billing & CRM) Software & Licenses etc.","netPrice":"5000.00","plannedDeliveryTime":"3","priceAdjustments":null,"priceBookCurrency":"EUR","priceErosionDetails":null,"priceUnit":"1","sapContractLineId":"2","supplierPartNumber":"UHDUSD","validFromDate":"2017-06-01T12:00:00.000Z","validToDate":"2022-06-01T12:00:00.000Z","volumeCommitment":null,"volumeDiscounts":null,"volumeTierDiscounts":null},"customGroup":null,"index":null,"isDeleted":false,"isReviewed":true,"lastSaveBy":null,"lastSaveDateTime":null,"lineStatus":"COMPLETE","priceReference":null},{"catalogue":{"assetClassDetails":[{}],"assetClassRequired":null,"baseUnitofMeasure":"PMI","bomParent":"Yes","commodityCodeTaric":"84158200","enLanguageKey":"EN","enMaterialLongText":"(ksjd , iusd)","grossWeightInKg":null,"height":null,"heightLengthWidthUnit":null,"length":null,"manufacturerPartNumber":"","materialLongDescription":"(ksjd , iusd)","physicalCategory":"Physical","volume":null,"volumeUnit":null,"width":null,"xxLanguageKey":null,"xxMaterialLongText":null},"catalogueStatus":"ACTIVE","catalogueStatusTimestamp":"2021-05-11T04:35:04.574Z","comment":null,"commercial":{"appliedVoucher":null,"commitmentDateCategory":null,"discountDateCategory":null,"manufacturer":"test123","materialDescription":"dsds3","materialGroupL4":"K103 - Customer Management (Billing & CRM) Software & Licenses etc.","netPrice":"6000.00","plannedDeliveryTime":"3","priceAdjustments":null,"priceBookCurrency":"EUR","priceErosionDetails":null,"priceUnit":"1","sapContractLineId":"2","supplierPartNumber":"DSDSDJJ","validFromDate":"2017-06-01T12:00:00.000Z","validToDate":"2022-06-01T12:00:00.000Z","volumeCommitment":null,"volumeDiscounts":null,"volumeTierDiscounts":null},"customGroup":null,"index":null,"isDeleted":false,"isReviewed":true,"lastSaveBy":null,"lastSaveDateTime":null,"lineStatus":"COMPLETE","priceReference":null},{"catalogue":{"assetClassDetails":[{}],"assetClassRequired":null,"baseUnitofMeasure":"PMI","bomParent":"Yes","commodityCodeTaric":"84158200","enLanguageKey":"EN","enMaterialLongText":"(ksjd ) ,( iusd)","grossWeightInKg":null,"height":null,"heightLengthWidthUnit":null,"length":null,"manufacturerPartNumber":"","materialLongDescription":"(ksjd ) ,( iusd)","physicalCategory":"Physical","volume":null,"volumeUnit":null,"width":null,"xxLanguageKey":null,"xxMaterialLongText":null},"catalogueStatus":"ACTIVE","catalogueStatusTimestamp":"2021-05-11T04:34:52.097Z","comment":null,"commercial":{"appliedVoucher":null,"commitmentDateCategory":null,"discountDateCategory":null,"manufacturer":"test123","materialDescription":"dsds4","materialGroupL4":"K103 - Customer Management (Billing & CRM) Software & Licenses etc.","netPrice":"5000.00","plannedDeliveryTime":"3","priceAdjustments":null,"priceBookCurrency":"EUR","priceErosionDetails":null,"priceUnit":"1","sapContractLineId":"2","supplierPartNumber":"TEST1","validFromDate":"2017-06-01T12:00:00.000Z","validToDate":"2022-06-01T12:00:00.000Z","volumeCommitment":null,"volumeDiscounts":null,"volumeTierDiscounts":null},"customGroup":null,"index":null,"isDeleted":false,"isReviewed":true,"lastSaveBy":null,"lastSaveDateTime":null,"lineStatus":"COMPLETE","priceReference":null},{"catalogue":{"assetClassDetails":[{}],"assetClassRequired":null,"baseUnitofMeasure":"PMI","bomParent":"Yes","commodityCodeTaric":"84158200","enLanguageKey":"EN","enMaterialLongText":"(ksjd) & " iusd"","grossWeightInKg":null,"height":null,"heightLengthWidthUnit":null,"length":null,"manufacturerPartNumber":"","materialLongDescription":"(ksjd) & " iusd"","physicalCategory":"Physical","volume":null,"volumeUnit":null,"width":null,"xxLanguageKey":null,"xxMaterialLongText":null},"catalogueStatus":"ACTIVE","catalogueStatusTimestamp":"2021-05-11T04:34:52.097Z","comment":null,"commercial":{"appliedVoucher":null,"commitmentDateCategory":null,"discountDateCategory":null,"manufacturer":"test123","materialDescription":"dsds5","materialGroupL4":"K103 - Customer Management (Billing & CRM) Software & Licenses etc.","netPrice":"5000.00","plannedDeliveryTime":"3","priceAdjustments":null,"priceBookCurrency":"EUR","priceErosionDetails":null,"priceUnit":"1","sapContractLineId":"2","supplierPartNumber":"1233","validFromDate":"2017-06-01T12:00:00.000Z","validToDate":"2022-06-01T12:00:00.000Z","volumeCommitment":null,"volumeDiscounts":null,"volumeTierDiscounts":null},"customGroup":null,"index":null,"isDeleted":false,"isReviewed":true,"lastSaveBy":null,"lastSaveDateTime":null,"lineStatus":"COMPLETE","priceReference":null}],"priceAgreementStatusTimestamp":"2021-05-11T04:36:52.000Z","priceAgreementStatus":"APPROVED","lastSaveBy":"cba089b2-807e-4924-806a-3105aa46cd70","lastSaveByOrganisation":"vodafoneMSP","lastSubmittedByOrganisation":"vodafoneMSP","lastSubmittedDateTime":"2021-05-11T04:35:14.000Z","lastSaveDateTime":"2021-05-11T04:36:52.000Z","version":"2","catalogueStatusTimestamp":"2021-05-11T04:36:52.000Z","catalogueStatus":"ACTIVE","exchangeRate":null,"conversionRateReference":null,"conversionChangeFrequency":null,"createdBy":"cba089b2-807e-4924-806a-3105aa46cd70","createdByOrganization":"vodafoneMSP","action":null,"creationTimestamp":"2021-05-10T11:14:12.000Z","type":"priceAgreement","counter":"8","requestForRevision":false,"materialCodeList":["K205 - ERP Software & Licenses","K103 - Customer Management (Billing & CRM) Software & Licenses etc."],"masterAgreement":{"type":"masterAgreement","catalogueType":"IT&E","duplicationCode":"ES00","masterAgreementId":"ERP2017MA005108","masterAgreementName":"NA","materialL4Details":[{"materialGroupL4Desc":"K205 - ERP Software & Licenses","materialGroupL4Id":"K205","olaLineItemId":"1","sirionLineItemId":null},{"materialGroupL4Desc":"K103 - Customer Management (Billing & CRM) Software & Licenses etc.","materialGroupL4Id":"K103","olaLineItemId":"2","sirionLineItemId":null},{"materialGroupL4Desc":"B218 - Customer Management (Billing & CRM) Systems & Software Maintenance, Support incl. SaaS","materialGroupL4Id":"B218","olaLineItemId":"4","sirionLineItemId":null}],"opcoCode":"LU68","opcoName":"Spain","organizationId":"oracle","outlineAgreementNumber":"1250027399","parentSupplier":"ORACLE CORPORATION UK LIMITED","purchasingIncoterm":"-","purchasingOrg":"LU07 - VF POrg Luxembourg","purchasingOrgCode":"LU07","supplierId":"0400017770","supplierName":"ORACLE CORPORATION UK LIMITED","tradingCurrencyKey":"EUR","tradingModel":"Buy From","validFromDate":"2017-06-01T00:00:00.000Z","validToDate":"2022-06-01T00:00:00.000Z","priceAgreementMetadata":{"catalogueType":"IT&E","catalogueName":"VPC_BF_IT_ORA_VFES_ICT_400017770_D76A18D","catalogueDescription":null,"priceAgreementReferenceName":"VPC_BF_IT_ORA_VFES_ICT_400017770_D76A18D","priceAgreementSupplierReferenceName":"VPC_BF_IT_ORA_VFES_ICT_400017770_D76A18D","catalogueGroup":"ES IT Catalogues - ES_IT_mask","initialCategoryManagerEmail":"cba089b2-807e-4924-806a-3105aa46cd70","initialSupplierManagerEmail":"fa52bb7d-63d8-43c6-8908-39387edb39f1"}},"priceAgreementId":"VPC_BF_IT_ORA_VFES_ICT_400017770_D76A18D"}
```

This is my java 8 code:

```
public static void main(String aa[]) {
    String test = "{\"priceAgreementLineDetails\":[{\"catalogue\":{\"assetClassDetails\":[{}],\"assetClassRequired\":null,\"baseUnitofMeasure\":\"PMI\",\"bomParent\":\"Yes\",\"commodityCodeTaric\":\"84158200\",\"enLanguageKey\":\"EN\",\"enMaterialLongText\":\"Lenovo Privacy Filter for 14\" Notebooks ( L, T and X1 Carbon)\"\",\"grossWeightInKg\":null,\"height\":null,\"heightLengthWidthUnit\":null,\"length\":null,\"manufacturerPartNumber\":\"\",\"materialLongDescription\":\"Lenovo Privacy Filter for 14\" Notebooks ( L, T and X1 Carbon)\"\",\"physicalCategory\":\"Physical\",\"volume\":null,\"volumeUnit\":null,\"width\":null,\"xxLanguageKey\":null,\"xxMaterialLongText\":null},\"catalogueStatus\":\"ACTIVE\",\"catalogueStatusTimestamp\":\"2021-05-11T04:34:52.097Z\",\"comment\":null,\"commercial\":{\"appliedVoucher\":null,\"commitmentDateCategory\":null,\"discountDateCategory\":\"custom\",\"manufacturer\":\"test123\",\"materialDescription\":\"dsds\",\"materialGroupL4\":\"K205 - ERP Software & Licenses\",\"netPrice\":\"7000.00\",\"plannedDeliveryTime\":\"3\",\"priceAdjustments\":null,\"priceBookCurrency\":\"EUR\",\"priceErosionDetails\":[{\"discount\":\"5.00\",\"validFrom\":\"2017-06-01T12:00:00.000Z\",\"validTo\":\"2022-06-01T12:00:00.000Z\"}],\"priceUnit\":\"1\",\"sapContractLineId\":\"1\",\"supplierPartNumber\":\"TESTING12321\",\"validFromDate\":\"2017-06-01T12:00:00.000Z\",\"validToDate\":\"2022-06-01T12:00:00.000Z\",\"volumeCommitment\":null,\"volumeDiscounts\":null,\"volumeTierDiscounts\":null},\"customGroup\":null,\"index\":null,\"isDeleted\":false,\"isReviewed\":true,\"lastSaveBy\":null,\"lastSaveDateTime\":null,\"lineStatus\":\"COMPLETE\",\"priceReference\":\"Purchase Order Date\"},{\"catalogue\":{\"assetClassDetails\":[{}],\"assetClassRequired\":null,\"baseUnitofMeasure\":\"PMI\",\"bomParent\":\"Yes\",\"commodityCodeTaric\":\"84158200\",\"enLanguageKey\":\"EN\",\"enMaterialLongText\":\"(ksjdiusd)\",\"grossWeightInKg\":null,\"height\":null,\"heightLengthWidthUnit\":null,\"length\":null,\"manufacturerPartNumber\":\"\",\"materialLongDescription\":\"(ksjdiusd)\",\"physicalCategory\":\"Physical\",\"volume\":null,\"volumeUnit\":null,\"width\":null,\"xxLanguageKey\":null,\"xxMaterialLongText\":null},\"catalogueStatus\":\"ACTIVE\",\"catalogueStatusTimestamp\":\"2021-05-11T04:34:52.097Z\",\"comment\":null,\"commercial\":{\"appliedVoucher\":null,\"commitmentDateCategory\":null,\"discountDateCategory\":null,\"manufacturer\":\"test123\",\"materialDescription\":\"dsds1\",\"materialGroupL4\":\"K103 - Customer Management (Billing & CRM) Software & Licenses etc.\",\"netPrice\":\"5000.00\",\"plannedDeliveryTime\":\"3\",\"priceAdjustments\":null,\"priceBookCurrency\":\"EUR\",\"priceErosionDetails\":null,\"priceUnit\":\"1\",\"sapContractLineId\":\"2\",\"supplierPartNumber\":\"TESTING123421\",\"validFromDate\":\"2017-06-01T12:00:00.000Z\",\"validToDate\":\"2022-06-01T12:00:00.000Z\",\"volumeCommitment\":null,\"volumeDiscounts\":null,\"volumeTierDiscounts\":null},\"customGroup\":null,\"index\":null,\"isDeleted\":false,\"isReviewed\":true,\"lastSaveBy\":null,\"lastSaveDateTime\":null,\"lineStatus\":\"COMPLETE\",\"priceReference\":null},{\"catalogue\":{\"assetClassDetails\":[{}],\"assetClassRequired\":null,\"baseUnitofMeasure\":\"PMI\",\"bomParent\":\"Yes\",\"commodityCodeTaric\":\"84158200\",\"enLanguageKey\":\"EN\",\"enMaterialLongText\":\"(ks) \"di\"\",\"grossWeightInKg\":null,\"height\":null,\"heightLengthWidthUnit\":null,\"length\":null,\"manufacturerPartNumber\":\"\",\"materialLongDescription\":\"(ks) \"di\"\",\"physicalCategory\":\"Physical\",\"volume\":null,\"volumeUnit\":null,\"width\":null,\"xxLanguageKey\":null,\"xxMaterialLongText\":null},\"catalogueStatus\":\"ACTIVE\",\"catalogueStatusTimestamp\":\"2021-05-11T04:34:54.353Z\",\"comment\":null,\"commercial\":{\"appliedVoucher\":null,\"commitmentDateCategory\":null,\"discountDateCategory\":null,\"manufacturer\":\"test123\",\"materialDescription\":\"dsds2\",\"materialGroupL4\":\"K103 - Customer Management (Billing & CRM) Software & Licenses etc.\",\"netPrice\":\"5000.00\",\"plannedDeliveryTime\":\"3\",\"priceAdjustments\":null,\"priceBookCurrency\":\"EUR\",\"priceErosionDetails\":null,\"priceUnit\":\"1\",\"sapContractLineId\":\"2\",\"supplierPartNumber\":\"UHDUSD\",\"validFromDate\":\"2017-06-01T12:00:00.000Z\",\"validToDate\":\"2022-06-01T12:00:00.000Z\",\"volumeCommitment\":null,\"volumeDiscounts\":null,\"volumeTierDiscounts\":null},\"customGroup\":null,\"index\":null,\"isDeleted\":false,\"isReviewed\":true,\"lastSaveBy\":null,\"lastSaveDateTime\":null,\"lineStatus\":\"COMPLETE\",\"priceReference\":null},{\"catalogue\":{\"assetClassDetails\":[{}],\"assetClassRequired\":null,\"baseUnitofMeasure\":\"PMI\",\"bomParent\":\"Yes\",\"commodityCodeTaric\":\"84158200\",\"enLanguageKey\":\"EN\",\"enMaterialLongText\":\"(ksjd , iusd)\",\"grossWeightInKg\":null,\"height\":null,\"heightLengthWidthUnit\":null,\"length\":null,\"manufacturerPartNumber\":\"\",\"materialLongDescription\":\"(ksjd , iusd)\",\"physicalCategory\":\"Physical\",\"volume\":null,\"volumeUnit\":null,\"width\":null,\"xxLanguageKey\":null,\"xxMaterialLongText\":null},\"catalogueStatus\":\"ACTIVE\",\"catalogueStatusTimestamp\":\"2021-05-11T04:35:04.574Z\",\"comment\":null,\"commercial\":{\"appliedVoucher\":null,\"commitmentDateCategory\":null,\"discountDateCategory\":null,\"manufacturer\":\"test123\",\"materialDescription\":\"dsds3\",\"materialGroupL4\":\"K103 - Customer Management (Billing & CRM) Software & Licenses etc.\",\"netPrice\":\"6000.00\",\"plannedDeliveryTime\":\"3\",\"priceAdjustments\":null,\"priceBookCurrency\":\"EUR\",\"priceErosionDetails\":null,\"priceUnit\":\"1\",\"sapContractLineId\":\"2\",\"supplierPartNumber\":\"DSDSDJJ\",\"validFromDate\":\"2017-06-01T12:00:00.000Z\",\"validToDate\":\"2022-06-01T12:00:00.000Z\",\"volumeCommitment\":null,\"volumeDiscounts\":null,\"volumeTierDiscounts\":null},\"customGroup\":null,\"index\":null,\"isDeleted\":false,\"isReviewed\":true,\"lastSaveBy\":null,\"lastSaveDateTime\":null,\"lineStatus\":\"COMPLETE\",\"priceReference\":null},{\"catalogue\":{\"assetClassDetails\":[{}],\"assetClassRequired\":null,\"baseUnitofMeasure\":\"PMI\",\"bomParent\":\"Yes\",\"commodityCodeTaric\":\"84158200\",\"enLanguageKey\":\"EN\",\"enMaterialLongText\":\"(ksjd ) ,( iusd)\",\"grossWeightInKg\":null,\"height\":null,\"heightLengthWidthUnit\":null,\"length\":null,\"manufacturerPartNumber\":\"\",\"materialLongDescription\":\"(ksjd ) ,( iusd)\",\"physicalCategory\":\"Physical\",\"volume\":null,\"volumeUnit\":null,\"width\":null,\"xxLanguageKey\":null,\"xxMaterialLongText\":null},\"catalogueStatus\":\"ACTIVE\",\"catalogueStatusTimestamp\":\"2021-05-11T04:34:52.097Z\",\"comment\":null,\"commercial\":{\"appliedVoucher\":null,\"commitmentDateCategory\":null,\"discountDateCategory\":null,\"manufacturer\":\"test123\",\"materialDescription\":\"dsds4\",\"materialGroupL4\":\"K103 - Customer Management (Billing & CRM) Software & Licenses etc.\",\"netPrice\":\"5000.00\",\"plannedDeliveryTime\":\"3\",\"priceAdjustments\":null,\"priceBookCurrency\":\"EUR\",\"priceErosionDetails\":null,\"priceUnit\":\"1\",\"sapContractLineId\":\"2\",\"supplierPartNumber\":\"TEST1\",\"validFromDate\":\"2017-06-01T12:00:00.000Z\",\"validToDate\":\"2022-06-01T12:00:00.000Z\",\"volumeCommitment\":null,\"volumeDiscounts\":null,\"volumeTierDiscounts\":null},\"customGroup\":null,\"index\":null,\"isDeleted\":false,\"isReviewed\":true,\"lastSaveBy\":null,\"lastSaveDateTime\":null,\"lineStatus\":\"COMPLETE\",\"priceReference\":null},{\"catalogue\":{\"assetClassDetails\":[{}],\"assetClassRequired\":null,\"baseUnitofMeasure\":\"PMI\",\"bomParent\":\"Yes\",\"commodityCodeTaric\":\"84158200\",\"enLanguageKey\":\"EN\",\"enMaterialLongText\":\"(ksjd) & \" iusd\"\",\"grossWeightInKg\":null,\"height\":null,\"heightLengthWidthUnit\":null,\"length\":null,\"manufacturerPartNumber\":\"\",\"materialLongDescription\":\"(ksjd) & \" iusd\"\",\"physicalCategory\":\"Physical\",\"volume\":null,\"volumeUnit\":null,\"width\":null,\"xxLanguageKey\":null,\"xxMaterialLongText\":null},\"catalogueStatus\":\"ACTIVE\",\"catalogueStatusTimestamp\":\"2021-05-11T04:34:52.097Z\",\"comment\":null,\"commercial\":{\"appliedVoucher\":null,\"commitmentDateCategory\":null,\"discountDateCategory\":null,\"manufacturer\":\"test123\",\"materialDescription\":\"dsds5\",\"materialGroupL4\":\"K103 - Customer Management (Billing & CRM) Software & Licenses etc.\",\"netPrice\":\"5000.00\",\"plannedDeliveryTime\":\"3\",\"priceAdjustments\":null,\"priceBookCurrency\":\"EUR\",\"priceErosionDetails\":null,\"priceUnit\":\"1\",\"sapContractLineId\":\"2\",\"supplierPartNumber\":\"1233\",\"validFromDate\":\"2017-06-01T12:00:00.000Z\",\"validToDate\":\"2022-06-01T12:00:00.000Z\",\"volumeCommitment\":null,\"volumeDiscounts\":null,\"volumeTierDiscounts\":null},\"customGroup\":null,\"index\":null,\"isDeleted\":false,\"isReviewed\":true,\"lastSaveBy\":null,\"lastSaveDateTime\":null,\"lineStatus\":\"COMPLETE\",\"priceReference\":null}],\"priceAgreementStatusTimestamp\":\"2021-05-11T04:36:52.000Z\",\"priceAgreementStatus\":\"APPROVED\",\"lastSaveBy\":\"cba089b2-807e-4924-806a-3105aa46cd70\",\"lastSaveByOrganisation\":\"vodafoneMSP\",\"lastSubmittedByOrganisation\":\"vodafoneMSP\",\"lastSubmittedDateTime\":\"2021-05-11T04:35:14.000Z\",\"lastSaveDateTime\":\"2021-05-11T04:36:52.000Z\",\"version\":\"2\",\"catalogueStatusTimestamp\":\"2021-05-11T04:36:52.000Z\",\"catalogueStatus\":\"ACTIVE\",\"exchangeRate\":null,\"conversionRateReference\":null,\"conversionChangeFrequency\":null,\"createdBy\":\"cba089b2-807e-4924-806a-3105aa46cd70\",\"createdByOrganization\":\"vodafoneMSP\",\"action\":null,\"creationTimestamp\":\"2021-05-10T11:14:12.000Z\",\"type\":\"priceAgreement\",\"counter\":\"8\",\"requestForRevision\":false,\"materialCodeList\":[\"K205 - ERP Software & Licenses\",\"K103 - Customer Management (Billing & CRM) Software & Licenses etc.\"],\"masterAgreement\":{\"type\":\"masterAgreement\",\"catalogueType\":\"IT&E\",\"duplicationCode\":\"ES00\",\"masterAgreementId\":\"ERP2017MA005108\",\"masterAgreementName\":\"NA\",\"materialL4Details\":[{\"materialGroupL4Desc\":\"K205 - ERP Software & Licenses\",\"materialGroupL4Id\":\"K205\",\"olaLineItemId\":\"1\",\"sirionLineItemId\":null},{\"materialGroupL4Desc\":\"K103 - Customer Management (Billing & CRM) Software & Licenses etc.\",\"materialGroupL4Id\":\"K103\",\"olaLineItemId\":\"2\",\"sirionLineItemId\":null},{\"materialGroupL4Desc\":\"B218 - Customer Management (Billing & CRM) Systems & Software Maintenance, Support incl. SaaS\",\"materialGroupL4Id\":\"B218\",\"olaLineItemId\":\"4\",\"sirionLineItemId\":null}],\"opcoCode\":\"LU68\",\"opcoName\":\"Spain\",\"organizationId\":\"oracle\",\"outlineAgreementNumber\":\"1250027399\",\"parentSupplier\":\"ORACLE CORPORATION UK LIMITED\",\"purchasingIncoterm\":\"-\",\"purchasingOrg\":\"LU07 - VF POrg Luxembourg\",\"purchasingOrgCode\":\"LU07\",\"supplierId\":\"0400017770\",\"supplierName\":\"ORACLE CORPORATION UK LIMITED\",\"tradingCurrencyKey\":\"EUR\",\"tradingModel\":\"Buy From\",\"validFromDate\":\"2017-06-01T00:00:00.000Z\",\"validToDate\":\"2022-06-01T00:00:00.000Z\",\"priceAgreementMetadata\":{\"catalogueType\":\"IT&E\",\"catalogueName\":\"VPC_BF_IT_ORA_VFES_ICT_400017770_D76A18D\",\"catalogueDescription\":null,\"priceAgreementReferenceName\":\"VPC_BF_IT_ORA_VFES_ICT_400017770_D76A18D\",\"priceAgreementSupplierReferenceName\":\"VPC_BF_IT_ORA_VFES_ICT_400017770_D76A18D\",\"catalogueGroup\":\"ES IT Catalogues - ES_IT_mask\",\"initialCategoryManagerEmail\":\"cba089b2-807e-4924-806a-3105aa46cd70\",\"initialSupplierManagerEmail\":\"fa52bb7d-63d8-43c6-8908-39387edb39f1\"}},\"priceAgreementId\":\"VPC_BF_IT_ORA_VFES_ICT_400017770_D76A18D\"}";
    JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(test));
    jsonReader.setLenient(true);
    try
    {
        while (jsonReader.hasNext()) 
        {
            JsonToken nextToken = jsonReader.peek();
             
            if (JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT.equals(nextToken)) {
                System.out.println("Begin object");
                jsonReader.beginObject();

            } else if (JsonToken.NAME.equals(nextToken)) {

                String name = jsonReader.nextName();
                System.out.println("Token KEY >>>> " + name);

            } else if (JsonToken.STRING.equals(nextToken)) {

                String value = jsonReader.nextString();
                System.out.println("Token Value >>>> " + value);

            } else if (JsonToken.NUMBER.equals(nextToken)) {

                long value = jsonReader.nextLong();
                System.out.println("Token Value >>>> " + value);

            } else if (JsonToken.NULL.equals(nextToken)) {

                jsonReader.nextNull();
                System.out.println("Token Value >>>> null");
                 
            } else if (JsonToken.END_OBJECT.equals(nextToken)) {
                System.out.println("End object");
                jsonReader.endObject();

            }
            else if (JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY.equals(nextToken)) {
                System.out.println("Begin array");
                jsonReader.beginArray();
            }
            else if (JsonToken.END_ARRAY.equals(nextToken)) {
                System.out.println("End array");
                jsonReader.endArray();
                
            }
            else if(JsonToken.END_DOCUMENT.equals(nextToken)) {
                System.out.println("End document");
            }
            
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            jsonReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The output it is giving is:

```
Begin object
Token KEY >>>> priceAgreementLineDetails
Begin array
Begin object
Token KEY >>>> catalogue
Begin object
Token KEY >>>> assetClassDetails
Begin array
Begin object
```

So when it is encountering an  empty object it is not progressing any further.
As this is an invalid json I expect it to fail but it is failing to early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm works in that way that once your code reaches ANY `END_OBJECT` token, it breaks out the only unnested `while` in your code. This happens because your code does not handle state for each particular complex subelement (i.e. arrays and objects), therefore the first empty object in `assetClassDetails` cannot be distinguished from the top object end. Either use a stack to hold a state of each subelement or use recursion:

```java
public final class StreamReadingTest {

    @Test
    public void test()
            throws IOException {
        try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = ... ) {
            jsonReader.setLenient(true);
            read(jsonReader);
        }
    }

    private static void read(final JsonReader jsonReader)
            throws IOException {
        read(jsonReader, 0);
    }

    private static void read(final JsonReader jsonReader, final int level)
            throws IOException {
        final JsonToken token = jsonReader.peek();
        switch ( token ) {
        case BEGIN_ARRAY:
            printMessage(level, "ARRAY");
            jsonReader.beginArray();
            while ( jsonReader.hasNext() ) {
                read(jsonReader, level + 1);
            }
            jsonReader.endArray();
            break;
        case END_ARRAY:
            throw new AssertionError();
        case BEGIN_OBJECT:
            printMessage(level, "OBJECT");
            jsonReader.beginObject();
            while ( jsonReader.hasNext() ) {
                printMessage(level, "| NAME = " + jsonReader.nextName());
                read(jsonReader, level + 1);
            }
            jsonReader.endObject();
            break;
        case END_OBJECT:
            throw new AssertionError();
        case NAME:
            throw new AssertionError();
        case STRING:
            printMessage(level, "STRING " + jsonReader.nextString());
            break;
        case NUMBER:
            printMessage(level, "NUMBER " + jsonReader.nextString()); // reading a string for not losing a precision
            break;
        case BOOLEAN:
            printMessage(level, "BOOLEAN " + jsonReader.nextBoolean());
            break;
        case NULL:
            jsonReader.nextNull();
            printMessage(level, "NULL");
            break;
        case END_DOCUMENT:
            printMessage(level, "END");
            break;
        default:
            throw new AssertionError(token);
        }
    }

    private static void printMessage(final int level, final String message) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < level; i++ ) {
            System.out.print("    ");
        }
        System.out.println(message);
    }

}
```

Once it's ran, it prints:

```
OBJECT
| NAME = priceAgreementLineDetails
    ARRAY
        OBJECT
        | NAME = catalogue
            OBJECT
            | NAME = assetClassDetails
                ARRAY
                    OBJECT
            | NAME = assetClassRequired
                NULL
            | NAME = baseUnitofMeasure
                STRING PMI
            | NAME = bomParent
                STRING Yes
            | NAME = commodityCodeTaric
                STRING 84158200
            | NAME = enLanguageKey
                STRING EN
            | NAME = enMaterialLongText
                STRING Lenovo Privacy Filter for 14
```

and

```
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 246 path $.priceAgreementLineDetails[0].catalogue.enMaterialLongText
```

as the JSON is invalid.

Comment: well this surely works. But I am also trying to fix invalid json which is another facet of the problem. Any idea?

Comment: @SubhenduMahanta I'm afraid Gson and all other JSON libraries can't help you on that, because any JSON documents must be valid to be parsed (applies to any grammar in general). You might want trying to extend those libraries loosening JSON rules, but I would suggest you to get a valid JSON if possible.